# How to convert WKT to SVG

Tags: javascript

I have some Well-known text (WKT) for representing geometry object such as Point, MultiPoint, LineString, Polygon, MultiPolygon etc. I have a multipolygon with in total 40000 Points.

I have found this plugin which convert svg to wkt
https://github.com/davidmcclure/svg-to-wkt

Is there any plugin which covert wkt to svg?

Comment: Are you exclusively looking for a javascript lib?

Comment: Yes I am looking for javascript library

Comment: You might take a slightly longer trip in your conversion, using MapBox's [wellknown](https://github.com/mapbox/wellknown) library to convert WKT to GeoJSON and then use [D3](http://d3js.org/) to display the GeoJSON as SVG Path element(s).